# I can't get the data stored in my function in my table out of this function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I created a table to store my data received with ajax but when I want to use  my table this return nothing there is my code :

```
var table = [];
function StreamLabs_First_Token(code_authorize){
  jQuery.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    url: "my url",
    data: {
      'grant_type': 'authorization_code',
      'client_id': 'my secret',
      'client_secret': 'my secret',
      'redirect_uri': 'myredirect uri',
      'code': code_authorize
    }
  }).done(function (data) {
    table.push({ id: data.access_token });
    console.log(table[0].id); //get the good id
  }).fail(function (data) {
    console.log(data);
  });
}
console.log(table[0].id); //get nothing
```

Comment: What does your console say?

Comment: Is the last `console.log()` running before the ajax promise is completed?

Comment: @SubhashShipu that is a **terrible** suggestion!! It is a bad practice and is deprecated. Never ever use `async:false`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The last line gets executed immediately after the ajax **request** has been made, at a time when the **response** has not arrived yet. So, no wonder the table is empty, because the data hasn't arrived yet.

Thats what the success callback function is for, where you correctly print the data. This is also the function in which to place any further code that is supposed to get executed **after** the response has arrived.